# How to enable persitence storage in jboss 6?

Tags: java, jboss, persistence

I have configured jms message queue in jboss and changed the default database to mysql db.
Now i want to enable persistence storage.

```
This is the horneq-configuration.xml file in jboss/server/default/deploy/hornetq  
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2009 Red Hat, Inc.
  ~  Red Hat licenses this file to you under the Apache License, version
  ~  2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  ~  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
  ~  implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
  ~  permissions and limitations under the License.
  -->

<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

   <log-delegate-factory-class-name>org.hornetq.integration.logging.Log4jLogDelegateFactory</log-delegate-factory-class-name>

   <bindings-directory>${jboss.server.data.dir}/hornetq/bindings</bindings-directory>

   <journal-directory>${jboss.server.data.dir}/hornetq/journal</journal-directory>

   <!-- Default journal file size is set to 1Mb for faster first boot -->
   <journal-file-size>${hornetq.journal.file.size:1048576}</journal-file-size>

   <!-- Default journal min file is 2, increase for higher average msg rates -->
   <journal-min-files>${hornetq.journal.min.files:2}</journal-min-files> 


   <large-messages-directory>${jboss.server.data.dir}/hornetq/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

   <paging-directory>${jboss.server.data.dir}/hornetq/paging</paging-directory>

   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </connector>

      <connector name="netty-throughput">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.batch.port:5455}"/>
         <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
      </connector>

      <connector name="in-vm">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="server-id" value="${hornetq.server-id:0}"/>
      </connector>

   </connectors>

   <acceptors>   
      <acceptor name="netty">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </acceptor>

      <acceptor name="netty-throughput">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.batch.port:5455}"/>
         <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
         <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
      </acceptor>

      <acceptor name="in-vm">
        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
        <param key="server-id" value="0"/>
      </acceptor>

   </acceptors>

   <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
         <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
      </security-setting>
   </security-settings>

   <address-settings>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
         <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
         <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
         <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
         <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>       
         <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
         <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      </address-setting>
   </address-settings>

</configuration>
```

Here what i need to change here? Can anyone tell me?
How to enable persistence in jboss 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the messages are actually stored in a persistent manner. From the [offical documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/):

> Each HornetQ server has its own ultra high performance persistent journal, which it uses for message and other persistence.

HornetQ has its own way of storing the messages directly on the file system.

If you want to store the messages in the MySQL database, this is not supported by HornetQ, and will probably not be in the future.

This has been debated a few times, for example [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/153581?tstart=120). The HornetQ team obviously don't think there is a need to add such support.

Comment: Thanks magnitex.Can you specify me location of "Messages directly on the file system". If server stops due to any exception how to take stored jms queue and where its located in jboss?

Comment: I guess this question is a bit out of scope of the original question. You congifure the file paths, e.g. ${jboss.server.data.dir}/hornetq/journal. I HornetQ has tools for viewing these, but I am not sure. You can also use Hermes JMS to browse the content of a queue.